# Bad rendering when importing a model in threejs using JSARToolkit

Tags: three.js, augmented-reality

**Hi all,**

I'm a chemistry teacher and I would like to use the JSARToolkit demo written by  Ilmari Heikkinen in html5 rocks http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webgl/jsartoolkit_webrtc/.

I'm a trying to use the threejs demo http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webgl/jsartoolkit_webrtc/AR_mediaStream_three.html with the latest `threejs` revision (n°58), adding a molecule mesh exported via blender with the `three.js` exporter(ver2.6).

Here's my code used to import the mesh.

```
function addModelToScene( geometry, materials )
    {
var material = new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial( materials );
        mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
        mesh.rotation.x = 2*Math.PI/2;
        mesh.rotation.y = 2*Math.PI/2;
        mesh.rotation.z = 2*Math.PI/2;
        mesh.position.x = 0;
        mesh.position.y =  0;
        mesh.position.z = -50;
        mesh.scale.set(30, 30, 30);
        m.model.matrixAutoUpdate=false;
        m.model.add(mesh);
        scene.add(m.model);
    }   

for(var i in markers){var m=markers[i];
    if(!m.model){m.model=new THREE.Object3D();
        var jsonLoader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
    jsonLoader.load( "models/eau.js", addModelToScene );
}
copyMatrix(m.transform,tmp);
m.model.matrix.setFromArray(tmp);
m.model.matrixWorldNeedsUpdate=true;
}
```

And here is the 3d model `eau.js` I'm using:https://gist.github.com/BenjaminABEL/5899604/raw/3c73e7561b82493d982bdb54be81180e4f331a48/eau.js

The problem is that the molecule appears transparent-like and black.
[image]

Although this model works right when I import it like in a simpler example like this one:https://github.com/stemkoski/stemkoski.github.com/blob/master/Three.js/Model.html.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem. A quick hack to this would be to set `material.side` to `THREE.DoubleSide` or `THREE.BackSide`.

It has something to do with different coordinate systems between JSARToolKit and Three.js. JSARToolKit is a left-handed coordinate system with -Z-up, while Three.js is a right-handed coordinate system with Y-up. If you do the conversion between these systems, it will appear correct. Some info that I wrote might be helpful: http://cg.skeelogy.com/google-summer-of-code-2013-week-2/#coordinates

EDIT: More info about the hack for a MeshFaceMaterial:

If your material is a MeshFaceMaterial, you need to iterate through its .materials array to get all the sub-materials, and then set those to double-sided.

```
var i, len;
for (i = 0, len = theMeshFaceMaterial.materials.length; i < len; i++) {
    theMeshFaceMaterial.materials[i].side = THREE.DoubleSide;
}
```

Just to double check that you have done this.

*UPDATE: I have released [skarf.js](http://cg.skeelogy.com/skarfjs/), a Three.js framework for JavaScript augmented reality libraries. I have integrated both JSARToolKit and js-aruco into the framework. One of the features is that it will take care of the above-mentioned coordinate system differences above for you, so you don't have to do the double-sided hack. Integration is easy, just a line of code to create a Skarf instance and another line to update it. You might want to give this a go, or at least take a look at the features before deciding if you want to use it.*

Comment: Thanks for these explanations, but the quick hack did not work. I'll try to understand better this problem later when I'll have little more time. Best results I had was using the `CanvasRenderer` instead of the `Webl` one.

Comment: Hmm I was pretty sure that I had the same problem. The object looks kind of inverted right? I have edited my answer to include some codes. Just to double check that you have iterated through the MeshFaceMaterial.materials to set the THREE.DoubleSide property?

Comment: It works great, thanks for these explanations, I didn't realize that I needed to make a loop on the mesh material imported.

Comment: I've added information about skarf.js which will help to eliminate the root of the problem that you are facing (the difference in coordinate systems)

Answer (score 0):

So to conclude, the `addModelToscene` function is(Thanks to skeelogy):

```
    function addModelToScene( geometry, materials )
    {
        var theMeshFaceMaterial = new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial( materials );
        var i, len;
        for (i = 0, len = theMeshFaceMaterial.materials.length; i < len; i++) {
            theMeshFaceMaterial.materials[i].side = THREE.DoubleSide;
        }
        mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, theMeshFaceMaterial );
        mesh.position.z = -50;
        mesh.scale.set(30, 30, 30);
        marker.object3d.add(mesh);
    }
```

And it works like a charm.

[image: Aspirin in the scene]

Comment: I've added information about skarf.js in my answer above, which will help to eliminate the root of the problem that you are facing (the difference in coordinate systems)